# Hide content in master page from view page

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I have a master page which is shared between about 20 views. In just one view, I need to make one small adjustment to the master page (I need to hide a textbox).

How can I include css or javascript in my view to acheive this?

Or is there some clever trick like including a conditional `<% if (View.Name = "blah") { ... } %>` that I can stick in my master page?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you can write a JavaScript code to achieve your goal and include it only in one view. In one of my projects I do the same: I have jQuery AJAX request only at one view, so I just used `script` tags to include it

Comment: but don't script tags need to go in the `<head>`? Do you just put them directly in the view?